# WWDC 2011 Sample Code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wwdc

Where can I download WWDC 2011's sample code from the videos?

I am a registered Apple Developer but did not go to WWDC. If I go to this link, then I only get videos with no code:

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

If I follow this link (a sample link from one of the many slideshow presentations) to download code, it won't let me because I didn't attend WWDC:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/schedule/details.php?id=419

Apple's site says "WWDC 2011 Conference Ticket Required."

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  "did not go to WWDC", and Apple's site says "WWDC 2011 Conference ticket required."

Comment: However it doesn't make sense for Apple to share the videos that revolve around examples without the sample code.  They provided the code for 2010 but there was a special link in iTunes. I'm thinking administrative error?

Comment: you have only to be a registered developer, not an attendee --- the videos and slides are currently available, i haven't seen the code yet, it _will_ be available at some point

Comment: I agree you only have to be a developer, at some point sounds just a little ominous.

Comment: For me it didn't work even though I was at WWDC.

Comment: I'm an attendee, doesn't work for me as well. "Access Denied"

Comment: @Andrew - after WWDC 2010 the sample code was available even to those who didn't attend.

Comment: Any news on this topic? It looks like it is still not possible to download the sample code from the WWDC 2011.

Answer (score 8):

Sample code is now on the [WWDC 2011 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) page; if you expand a session, "Sample Code" links will be under the "Presentation Slides" link. Not every session had sample code.

As it happens, the links in some presentation slides were attendee-centric, and haven't aged as well as they could, but you can find the sample code next to the slides or video.

Comment: It must've moved again.  Every session on the page you've linked to has “Download: HD | SD | PDF” links, but not a single Sample Code link.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, there is no sample code package, there is a script on GitHub to download all the session material: https://github.com/davidcann/WWDC2011-Downloader but you need to be an attendee to use it.

Comment: Ya my buddy who went just tried it.. doesn't even work for those who attended!

Comment: It worked for me some days ago, maybe the portal structure have changed.

Comment: Can you verify it works today?

Comment: The link doesn't work at all.